# C# Viewstate - cant retrieve table

Tags: c#, postback, viewstate

I have a datatable containing file paths which I am passing via viewstate (referencing, via a linkbutton, an index in this table), wanting to then use the path from the table to construct a HTTP filetransfer. (So 3 cols; name, path and index)

I am unable to successfully retrieve the datatable once saved in viewstate;

```
   ViewState["varFiles"] = filedata;
```

(When page is originally constructed, then after postback:)

```
if (!IsPostBack) { SetupSession(); newpopfiles(); }
    else { { if (ViewState["varFiles"] != null) { DataTable filedata = new DataTable(); filedata = (DataTable)Session["varFiles"]; } } }
```

From what I understand this should pull back filedata as a table in exactly the same form as before postback. Is this correct?

When subsequently referencing the table I get a null reference exception. Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: `Session` != `ViewState`. (Check the code for why this observation is meaningful.)

Comment: why are you using session , if datatable is stored in viewstate

Comment: Ah. Thanks guys - I had extracted this from a previous example and had thought Session was a means of extracting from ViewState.

Comment: Though switching to Viewstate still doesnt solve it - any idea what I might be doing wrong? Why might the page, after postback, see filedata as null even with this retrieval step?

Comment: try to use ViewData instead ViewState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're almost there, just need to be a bit more consistent with using the same storage mechanism :)

The bit to save the `DataTable` into your session, probably in `OnInit()` or `PageLoad()`:

```
DataTable myDataTable = //... fill it in somehow
Session["varFiles"] = myDataTable;
```

The bit to read the `DataTable` after postback:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    SetupSession();
    newpopfiles();
}
else
{
    DataTable filedata = Session["varFiles"] as DataTable;
    if (filedata != null)
    {
        //... do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Only a *bit* harder :) Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I am trying to upvote but apparently dont have the reputation yet :( Thanks again for your help though.